# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm working on an inventory function, however, I keep getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined. I don't think I'm going over the length of array, so why am I getting "property '1' undefined". Obviously I"m trying to read something is not there. I just can't see it. Any help appreciated. I used the console.log to try to log the error. but everything comes back with an output. Thanks

```js
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
        // All inventory must be accounted for or you're fired!
      for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        //if item found, update
        var index = findItem(arr1[i][1], arr2);
        if(index != undefined) {
          arr1[i][0] += arr2[i][0];
        }
        else {
          arr1.push(arr2[index]);
        }
          
        }
      
      
      //sort arr1
      arr1.sort(function(first, second) {
        return (first[1] > second[1]) ? 1 : -1;
      });
      
        return arr1;
    }
    
    //helper method to search arr2
    function findItem(item, arr2) {
      for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if(item === arr2[i][1])
          return i;
      }
      return undefined;
    }
    // Example inventory lists
    var curInv = [
        [21, "Bowling Ball"],
        [2, "Dirty Sock"],
        [1, "Hair Pin"],
        [5, "Microphone"]
    ];
    
    var newInv = [
        [2, "Hair Pin"],
        [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
        [67, "Bowling Ball"],
        [7, "Toothpaste"]
    ];
    
    updateInventory(curInv, newInv);
```

Comment: And that error probably comes with a line number

Comment: You are using `[1]` in a lot of places; which does the error refer to?

Comment: Just a note here - I'd advise pushing things onto arrays that you're iterating over, as it makes things way more complex! Try building an array of stuff to add during the loop, and then push it all at the end.

Answer (score 3):

in the code `else { arr1.push(arr2[index]); }` index will be undefined here. which will result in undefined getting pushed into arr1, and you are running loop over same array. so `var index = findItem(arr1[i][1], arr2)` will give the error you see. It will be better if you update the other array with updated values.

```js
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
// All inventory must be accounted for or you're fired!
  for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
//if item found, update
var index = findItem(arr1[i][1], arr2);
if(index != undefined) {
  arr2[index][0] += arr1[i][0];
}else{
  arr2.push(arr1[i]);
}
  }


  //sort arr2
  arr2.sort(function(first, second) {
return (first[1] > second[1]) ? 1 : -1;
  });

return arr2;
}

//helper method to search arr2
function findItem(item, arr2) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
if(item === arr2[i][1])
  return i;
  }
  return undefined;
}
// Example inventory lists
var curInv = [
[21, "Bowling Ball"],
[2, "Dirty Sock"],
[1, "Hair Pin"],
[5, "Microphone"]
];

var newInv = [
[2, "Hair Pin"],
[3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
[67, "Bowling Ball"],
[7, "Toothpaste"]
];

console.log(updateInventory(curInv, newInv));
```

Comment: no I have to update arr1 with the difference in arr2. whatever items in arr2 not in arr1 need to be added. If item already exists then update quantity